# Mercurial - Convert error - unable to convert merge commit

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-convert

I have a huge repository with many subfolders in the following layout:

```
MainRepo
├── Folder1
├── Folder2
├── Folder3
├── Folder4
└── Folder5
```

I'm trying to create another repo from folders `Folder1, Folder2 and Folder3`.

To do that I created the filemap to use in convert like this:

```
include Folder1
include Folder2
include Folder3
rename .
```

But when I try to convert the repository using:

```
hg convert  --filemap filemap MainRepo/ NewRepo
```

I get the following error:

```
...
<rev> message
1136 Merge with default
abort: unable to convert merge commit since target parents do not merge cleanly (file Folder1/Project1.csproj, parents 65b9b85aa32c and 923b315f094c)
```

Does any one had this kind of problem in the past? How to get rid of this kind of error? I tried to close branches that were merged with default, but it was of no help.

Also, where I can find resources on how to clean up repos? This repo uses a lot of named branches and they are very messy.

Comment: Probable dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430015/mercurial-convert-with-filemap-fails-with-any-dummy-rename/67536721#67536721

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by closing all my inactive heads and also removing the `rename .` at the end. For what I wanted it worked just fine.